# JQuery: Click anywhere other than #element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Nothing in the recommended questions covers it.  I'm trying to initiate an event if a click occurs anywhere in the document other than in one of two specific divs.  This is what I'm doing:

```
$('html:not(#optionsDropdown):not(#settingsButton)').click(function() {
    if ($('#settingsCogCheck').val() === '1') {
        alert('click');
    }
});
```

It isn't working, though.  Any clue as to why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add a listener to "everything except x", but you can listen on `document`, and check the element inside the click handler:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    var id = $(this).id;
    if (id != 'optionsDropdown' && id != 'settingsButton') {
        if ($('#settingsCogCheck').val() === '1') {
            alert('click');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it should be `function(e) {
    var id = e.target.id;` i think

Comment: Nevermind, GOT IT.  The problem was to check a class (I paraphrased a bit on this question) I had to wrap e.target in a JQuery Object.